# obj-c images resizing automatically...?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, image, xcode5

I just started learning obj-c the other day and i'm putting together a crappy game as practice. I have an IMG as a main character to the game and every time this character hits certain obstacles, i wanted the size of the image to change (decrease or increase depending on the circumstance).

I used photoshop the change the size of the images to the appropriate sizes but for some reason, when i run the game, the images change when i want them too, but they are way smaller than the size i set them to in photoshop......

any ideas?

i don't think its necessary to post my code for something as simple as this, right? its just a simple "if" statement followed by the instance and the UIimage named for the image name...

Comment: Are the images scaled for retina resolution? You should provide an image with 2x the number of pixels in relation to the displayed size of the image in points

Comment: Hm, i doubled the images size and it still resizes to something way too small...

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: if (ScoreNumber > 4){ Character.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Large.png"]; }

Comment: so when the score reaches 5, the image should change to the named image, which is double the size in pixels of the original image....but for some reason, on display, its smaller when it changes.....it does change, nothing wrong with the code...its just not the specified size.

Comment: Do you also resize the view after either manually using the size of the `UIImage` or with `sizeToFit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you display the image in an `UIImageView`? Or do you use `SpriteKit`? If you use an `UIImageView` the image is actually automatically scaled to the size of the `UIImageView`.

Therefore you would just change the size of the `UIImageView` (you can of course also change the image inside the `UIImageView`.

If you are using `SpriteKit`, you have to remember, that your are probably testing on a 'retina' device and for this reason the image's width and height is divided by 2 (the real resolution of the current iPhone 5/5s is 1136x640 and not 568x320 !

Comment: I am using UIImageView in a single view app. So the game starts with a character of a certain size. I coded it so that when a certain event happens, the UIImage changes into a completely new image. This new image is supposed to be bigger than the original character of the game. (when the code i wrote is true). I made sure the new image is double the size in pixels than the original image....but still not working

Comment: if (ScoreNumber > 4){
        
        Character.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Large.png"];
        
    }

Comment: as I said, the pixel size of the .png file does not matter in case of UIImageView ! What you can do is: UIImage *chrImage =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Large.png"]; CGPoint center = Character.center; Character.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,chrImage.size.width,chrImage.size.height); Character.center = center;   that should help you!